# Express.js req.body is undefined when getting callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, dribbble-api

I'm trying to receive a callback from the Dribbble Auth API. The Authentication process is working fine until I'm trying to fetch the response data with NodeJS.

My Callback-URL is `http://localhost:8080/callback`
A callback url looks like this `http://localhost:8080/callback?code=11ee328ab7935bd7240cbff0a2d0b8c93e96547e0a3&state=aoksdmSAOKDm`

I'm using body-parser and multer.

```
var express = require("express");
var multer = require("multer");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../webapp/")));

app.get("/callback",  upload.single("code"), (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send()
}
```

The response in the console is **undefined**

Comment: `var express = require('express');` not `const app = express();`

Comment: Couldn't change anything with that. But changed it now in my question @ZombieChowder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query isn't in `req.body` with a GET request. you have to do:

```
req.query
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a GET request.Please check

```
req.query
```

More details refer
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html